# Convert list of integers to a single integer : ValueError

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, integer

I am trying to convert a list of integers in Python into a single integer say for example `[1,2,3,4]` to `1234`(integer). In my function, I am using following piece of code:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
b = int(''.join(map(str, L)))
return b
```

The compiler throws a `ValueError`. Why so? How to rectify this issue?

Comment: It works fine on my machine. Nevertheless, this is *not* the recommended way to construct an joined integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this also if that cause problems:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
maxR = len(L) -1 
res = 0
for n in L:
  res += n * 10 ** maxR
  maxR -= 1
print(res)
```

> 1234

Answer (score 0):

another solution would be

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
digitsCounter = 1

def digits(num):
  global digitsCounter
  num *= digitsCounter
  digitsCounter *= 10
  return num

sum(map(digits, L[::-1]))
```

the `digits()` is a non pure function that takes a number and places it on place value depending on the iteration calling digits on each iteration

```
 1. digits(4) = 4 1st iteration
 2. digits(4) = 40 2nd iteration
 3. digits(4) = 400 3rd iteration
```

when we sum up the array returned by map from the inverted list L[::-1] we get 1234 since every digit in the array is hoisted to it place value
if we choose not no invert L array to L[::-1] then we would need our digits function to do more to figure out the place value of each number in the list so we use this to take adv of language features